# 'verbose_name': _('Small screens') NameError: name '_' is not defined

Tags: django, django-templates

After installation django-responsive2 as [django-responsive2](https://django-responsive2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html), i got following error:

```
'verbose_name': _('Small screens')
NameError: name '_' is not defined
```

I use
`from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _`.
I got this error:

```
mw_instance = middleware(adapted_handler)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Next i used

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy
'verbose_name': gettext_lazy('Small screens')
```

but i got previous error again.
finally i used `'verbose_name': 'Small screens'` and got this error:

[image]

MIDDLEWARE is:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
        'responsive.middleware.ResponsiveMiddleware',
    ]
```

Comment: This is not the full traceback... You should share the *full* traceback, since the problem arises somewhere else than in the Django framework codebase.

Comment: How do i can do it? is there any document?

Comment: you select the entire traceback, and you copy the traceback. This thus has a cascade of references to files, like [this](https://guido.vonrudorff.de/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/classic.png).

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Can you share your `MIDDLEWARE` setting (as code, not as image).

Comment: it looks like the `django-responsive2` is "dead": it has had no commits the last three years, but more importantly, it writes middleware in the "old" way, not the new one: https://github.com/mishbahr/django-responsive2/blob/master/responsive/middleware.py Perhaps it can be "upgraded" with a mixin, but I think that belongs in another question.

Comment: How can i accept this answer? Thank you

Comment: you likely will have to make a middleware class yourself that inherits from both the middleware class in the old style, and the `MiddlewareMixin` from `django.utils.deprecation`. Likely that will solve the problem with the mixin, but since the project has not been updated for the last three years, it will likely only get us to the next problem.

Comment: therefore it might be better to look for a package that has been maintained up till now and provides the tooling that you need. Especially since Django itself moves forward, and a "dead" package will eventually be that deprecated, that it will take days to adapt it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django `_` is used as a short identifier to refer to the [**`gettext_lazy(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy). You need to import this (at the top of your file):

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
```

You can also import this simply as `gettext_lazy` and then use this later in the program:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy

# …

'verbose_name': gettext_lazy('Small screens')
```

Or if you do not plan to make your app available in other languages, you just use the string literal, so removing the <s>`_(…)`</s> part:

```
'verbose_name': 'Small screens'
```

Comment: can i use it without _ ? for example 'verbose_name': 'Small screens'. ii think _ is for translation and i don't want to use it.

Comment: @namjoo.org: if you do not want to translate it (later) then you can omit the `_(...)` part yes.

Comment: after
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
i get this error:
mw_instance = middleware(adapted_handler)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Comment: @namjoo.org: well likely a lot of things are broken, so if one item is fixed, it errors on the next thing. Edit the question and add the *full* traceback.